# New Button Window and UI Alignment

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

I created a main window where the user will click if he's a system admin, an employee or a member a finance, one of my problem is that they are not centered in the screen, how would I do that? Second, I want it to work like, when I click the Finance Button, the Mainwindow Will close and it will bring me to my  log in screen, how would I do that?? Here's my MainWindow Code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


    public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

        private JPanel contentPane;

        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */
        public MainWindow() {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 333, 191);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

            JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Employee");
            contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.WEST);

            JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Finance");
            btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Login login = new Login();
                }
            });
            contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("System Admin");
            contentPane.add(btnNewButton_2, BorderLayout.EAST);

            JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Welcome");
            contentPane.add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }

    }
```

here is my code for a login form

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Login extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label1, label2;
    private JButton submit;
    private JTextField textfield1;
    private JPasswordField passfield;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Login() {

        setSize(300, 100);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        label1 = new JLabel("User ID:");
        textfield1 = new JTextField(15);
        label2 = new JLabel("Password:");
        passfield = new JPasswordField(15);
        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(textfield1);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(passfield);
        panel.add(submit);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
        submit.addActionListener(handler);
    }// end login constructor

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            String user = textfield1.getText();
            char[] passChars = passfield.getPassword();
            Connection conn = Jdbc.dbConn();
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String pass = new String(passChars);

            if (passChars != null) {
                String sql = "SELECT employee_ID, employee_password FROM  user WHERE employee_ID = ? AND employee_password = ?";

                try {
                    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps.setString(1, user);
                    ps.setString(2, pass);
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome! "+user);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Input");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        rs.close();
                        ps.close();
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                            ee.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }// end actionPerformed
        }// End ButtonHandler
    }// End of class
}
```

Comment: your question mark key seems to be stuck a bit :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Do not use `setBounds()` for `MainWindow` (JFrame). Use some Layout and at end use `pack()`. If you want to set size manually then you can also use `setSize()`.
2. To close current window and open Login frame add `setVisible(false)` or `dispose()` and create Login object and make it visible.
3. For making frame to be at center try `setLocationRelativeTo(null);`.
4. Do not use variable names like `label1`, `textFiled2`, `btnNewButton`, etc... Use proper names for proper variable that reflects it usage.

---

Example for point 2:

```
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            setVisible(false);
            Login login = new Login();
        }
    });
```

Comment: soo what I'll do is after I click the Finance button, I'll create an object then I'll set it's visible to false? or i'll use dispose()??

Answer (score 3):

You need to [carefully choose a layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to suit your needs. You are currently using `BorderLayout` which doesn't seem to do what you want.

Try adding your three buttons to a `JPanel` and then setting that panel as your frame's content pane. `JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` by default which should do the trick.

Comment: EDIT: How would I show my Login form with that kind of approach??

Comment: Please don't put code in comments.  It becomes unreadable.  Edit it into the question as an update and let the person know in a comment that the question is updated.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, I added my Login code, how would I insert that in the JButton? if the user Clicks the Finance button, the Mainwindow will close and it will bring them to the Login Form, how would I do that??

Comment: If this frame with the three buttons is just acting as a kind of launcher, then you can just create a new `JFrame` for your login screen and dispose the launcher frame. Alternatively you might look into using a `JDialog` for the login.

Comment: How would I do that with my code? I was thinking to when I click the Finance Button it will bring me to the log in screen(Log in Object) and then it will dispatch or close the MainWindow or also known as Launcher window how would I do that???